# Using Boostrap, how can I make a menu close after clicking outside?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

As of right now, I am not using any JS to open/close the hamburger menu. I'm using Boostrap's built in feature to open/close it.

My HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
   <h3 class="brandname">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif; font-weight: 600;">Raffle<span>Hive</span></a>
   </h3>
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="javascript:void(0);"></a>
   <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarsExample01" aria-controls="navbarsExample01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
   <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   </button>
   <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarsExample01" style="">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto align-items-center">
         <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active jumper" style="font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif; font-weight: 500;" aria-current="page" href="#home">Home</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item ms-2">
            <a class="nav-link jumper" style="font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif; font-weight: 500;" href="#features">Features</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item ms-2">
            <a class="nav-link jumper" style="font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif; font-weight: 500;" href="#statistics">Statistics</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item  ms-2">
            <a class="nav-link jumper" style="font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif; font-weight: 500;" aria-current="page" href="#plans">Plans</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item  ms-2">
            <a class="nav-link jumper" style="font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif; font-weight: 500;" href="#faq">FAQ</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item  ms-3">
            <a class="nav-link btn btn-primary py-1 px-4" style="font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif; font-weight: 500;" href="#">Dashboard</a>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

The user should be able to click anywhere outside (below in this case) to close the menu without having to just click the hamburger icon.

I believe I'll need to use JS if I'm not mistaken, but not sure where to start.

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
     $(document).ready(function () { 
     $(document).click(function () {
     // if($(".navbar-collapse").hasClass("in")){
     $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
     // }
     });
     });
```

Fixed this.